# Shopify if statement

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I need to run some logic for products where the vendor is a specific vendor and if the product is out of stock, disable the 'Add Free Sample' button. (the code for disabling the button is already set,) Here is the code below:

```html
{%- comment -%}SAMPLE LOGIC{%- endcomment -%}
{% if has_free_sample %}
  {%- comment -%} check if there is > 4 samples or an existing sample of the same in the cart {%- endcomment -%}
  {% assign maxSamples = false %}
  {% assign sampleInCart = false %}
  {% assign sampleCount = 0 %}
  {% for item in cart.items %}
    {% if size_option == item.variant_id %}
      {% assign sampleInCart = true %}
      {% break %}
    {% endif %}

    {%- comment -%}check if its a sample{%- endcomment -%}
    {% assign isASample = false %}
    {% for option in item.options_with_values %}
      {% if option.value contains 'Sample' %}
        {% assign isASample = true %}
        {% break %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if isASample %}
      {% assign sampleCount = sampleCount | plus: 1 %}
      {% if sampleCount == 4 %}
        {% assign maxSamples = true %}
        {% break %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% assign isInStock = true %}
    {% if product.vendor == 'PS-Stock' and product.available == false %}
      {% assign isInStock = false %}
    {% endif %}


  {%- comment -%}ADD SAMPLE {%- endcomment -%}
  {% if maxSamples == false and sampleInCart == false and isInStock == true %}
    <input type="hidden" data-free-sample-quantity-input max="1"/>
    <button {% unless current_variant.available %}disabled{% endunless %} 
    data-product-form-submit
    data-in-stock-text="{{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t: unit: order_measurement }}"
    data-unavailable-text="{{ 'products.product.unavailable' | t }}"
    data-oos-text="{{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}"
    data-success-text="{{ 'products.product.added_to_cart' | t }}"
    data-add-to-cart
    data-atc-quantity-input="[data-free-sample-quantity-input]"
    data-atc-product-id="{{ size_option }}"
    data-is-sample="true"
    data-max-samples="{{ 'products.product.max_samples' | t }}"
    data-sample-added-text="{{ 'products.product.sample_added' | t }}"
    data-sample-added-error-toast-text="{{ 'products.product.sample_added_error_toast' | t }}"
    type="submit"
    class="btn--atc btn btn-primary">{{ 'products.product.add_to_cart_free_sample' | t }}</button>
  {% else %}
    <button 
      disabled
      data-max-samples="{{ 'products.product.max_samples' | t }}"
      data-in-stock-text="{{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t: unit: order_measurement }}"
      data-unavailable-text="{{ 'products.product.unavailable' | t }}"
      data-oos-text="{{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}"
      data-success-text="{{ 'products.product.added_to_cart' | t }}"
      data-atc-product-id="{{ size_option }}"
      data-is-sample="true"
      type="submit"
      class="btn--atc btn btn-primary">
      {% if maxSamples %}
        {{ 'products.product.max_samples' | t }}
      {% else %}
        {{ 'products.product.sample_added' | t }}
      {% endif %}
    </button>
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

I have a feeling the issue may lie somewhere with the 'isInStock' variable but not sure. I need it to only disable the button if its the certain vendor is the one specified and the product is out of stock

Comment: What is the problem? What is the result of your code? Is not clear what is wrong.

Comment: apologies, so i've got a couple of variables defined with if statements which are checking to see if the max number of samples have been reached etc. I have 2 options for how a button will be displayed on the product description page based on the value of the variables, one being it disables the 'add to cart' btn. 

I have added another variable called 'isInStock' as shown above which I want to show the disabled button instead of normal btn if the product is out of stock and the vendor is a specific vendor. So far the code i have doesnt seem to be working as the btn is not the disabled btn

Comment: Try to split the condition, with multiple ifs if needed. And see what happens. I always end up not using logic operator with liquid.